# Select from multiple tables without cartesian product

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to create a command to copy the details of client memberships from one database to another with identical structure. I've pared it down to the bare essentials for the purposes of the question so the four items to copy are the expiry date, the subscription ID, the client ID and the item ID (which is the service which comprises the subscription).
The clients have a common GUID in both bases. The subscription ID is a unique long int which should be the same in both bases and the expiry date is just a date. So far, so easy. The tricky part is that the item_id is not necessarily the same in each database. I need to map from one to the the other with a where statement, which I know how to do.

My problem is that I need to select from the destination database's own ITEM table (item_0) in order to get and insert the correct item_id and when I do this I get thousands of duplicate rows returned. I assume I need to use a join to avoid this but as I have nothing meaningful to join item_0 to I can't get any results.

```
insert into DestDB..subscription (expiry_date,id,client_id,item_id)
select 
    sub_1.expiry_date,
    sub_1.id,
    cli_0.id as client_id,
    item_0.id as item_id,
from SourceDB..subscription sub_1,
    DestDB..item item_0,
    DestDB..client cli_0
inner join SourceDB..client cli_1
   on cli_1.[guid] = cli_0.[guid] 
where sub_1.id not in (select id from DestDB..subscription)  
and item_0.id = 
     (select id from DestDB..collectiondetails 
             where service_ID =
              (select id from DestDB..service s_0 where s_0.code = 
                 (select code from SourceDB..service s_1 where s_1.id = 
                    (select service_ID from Source..collectiondetails item_1         where item_1.id = sub_1.item_id)))
             and collection_ID =
               (select id from DestDB..collection col_0
                  where col_0.code = 
                    (select code from SourceDB..collection col_1 where col_1.id =
                       (select collection_ID from SourceDB..collectiondetails item_1 where item_1.id = sub_1.collection_ID)))

     )
```

Comment: How tables DestDB..item and DestDB..client are connected, is there any FK?

Comment: There's no direct connection between them. Both are connected to DestDB.subscription by subscription.client_id and subscription.item_id

Comment: If you "have nothing meaningful to join item_0" how do you want to select a correct item for a given subscription. There must be something. Otherwise you can select a random item as well.

Comment: I didn't want to give the full structure as it's kind of complicated but I guess I need to make it a bit clearer! The 'item' is part of a collection of items and this collection exists in both databases with separate IDs but a common CODE field. The item_ID in the subscription table actually refers to the id of the item within its collection.

Comment: So item_ID 1 tells you to look at item 1 in the collection table where you find a link to the ID of the item itself. I've been doing this matchup in a where statement at the end. I'll amend that with the full information.

Comment: ay ay ay, I've just seen now that I've retyped it here what I was missing - a clause in the AND statement that links the client_ID to the ID of the client in the Source table!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the updated question is even more confusing. Is this `Select` in `Where` clause guaranteed to return one record only or should it be `in` instead of `=`?

If there is no rule to identify a particular `DestDB..item` from the list of matching then the top one should do as well. It would still seem that `item_0` can be omitted altogether:

```
insert into DestDB..subscription (expiry_date,id,client_id,item_id)
select 
    sub_1.expiry_date,
    sub_1.id,
    cli_0.id as client_id,
    (select Top 1 id from DestDB..collectiondetails   --<- Limit to top 1 only
             where service_ID =
              (select id from DestDB..service s_0 where s_0.code = 
                 (select code from SourceDB..service s_1 where s_1.id = 
                    (select service_ID from SourceDB..collectiondetails item_1 where item_1.id = sub_1.item_id)))
             and collection_ID =
               (select id from DestDB..collection col_0
                  where col_0.code = 
                    (select code from SourceDB..collection col_1 where col_1.id =
                       (select collection_ID from SourceDB..collectiondetails item_1 where item_1.id = sub_1.collection_ID)))
     ) as item_id,
from SourceDB..subscription sub_1,
    DestDB..client cli_0
inner join SourceDB..client cli_1
   on cli_1.[guid] = cli_0.[guid] 
where sub_1.id not in (select id from DestDB..subscription)
```

Please note: if `DestDB..item` is empty the question example statement would not insert anything, but this answer one - would with `item_id` set to `NULL`.

I personally would try splitting this task into two separate statements in one transaction:

1. Insert into target table with NULL item_id.
2. Update target table with new item_id where item_id is NULL.
3. (optional) Delete unwanted records where appropriate item_id could not be found.

Comment: see above. Sorry for the vagueness in the original question, I was trying to limit confusion by posting too much info but I realise I was unclear.